# What is the equation that fits this curve?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, regression

I have a curve that looks like this (it's cyclical):

[Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QH3J.png)

I can get a partial fit by fitting a 3rd degree polynomial, but I have a feeling there must be a better fit (something that involves sin & cos).

The fitted $a*t^3 + b*t$ curve looks like this:

[Fitted Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWQin.png)

Any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to fit higher-order polynomials, which should give you the flexibility needed to ensure differentiability or some such constraint. Or if you're willing to try parametric curves, you can get a fit relatively easily, like [$$x(t)=\sin(t)+t, y(t)=\sin(t)$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bsin%28t%29%2Bt%2Csin%28t%29%7D)

I assume that you explicitly want the skewed nature of the wave in your picture. Tuning the amount of skew, height, etc. in the parametric formula is just a matter of tweaking a few parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\Delta \approx \dfrac{\hat\tau - \tau}{2}$, then we have:

$$ f(\Delta ) \sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{2\Delta}\right) $$

Where $f(\Delta)$ is the value of the function at $\Delta$.